# Modded Minecraft COFH skin set

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I have recently installed the Monster FTB pack on my server. In 1.5.2 (Unleashed) we were able to use the command /cofh skin set

When we use the command on the server, a message appears that the skin change was successful but the skins just always stay the default Steve.

Is there something special we need to do to enable the usage of custom skins on our server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault for not reading thoroughly. From the change log in case anyone else is experiencing this issue.

http://teamcofh.com/index.php?page=changelog

Skins and Capes are disabled in 1.6.4 and functionality is expected to be restored in 1.7.x

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading [this CoFH page](http://wiki.feed-the-beast.com/HD_Capes_and_Skins) correctly, this command allows you (the player) to set your own skin when followed by the url where the skin is hosted.

```
/cofh skin set [url]
```

It also mentions that there is a server command to allow you to set capes for other users, but doesn't mention anything about setting another player's skin.

Comment: Ops can set skins for other players. Players also cannot set their own skins, the same result happens with the command you have above, the message in chat reads that it was successful, however the skin does not actually change, it remains the default.